# session.save_path disallowing sessions from starting

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

**Context**

I own a shared server on Bluehost, so my sessions time out after just a few minutes. Trying to fix this, I found that I can use the combination of `ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime, "21600")` and `ini_set("session.save_path", "../session")` (I created a folder "session" outside of the site's root folder) to change the session timeout time. The maxlifetime function seems to work fine; however, after setting the second function (the save path function), I can no longer log into my website, meaning the sessions are no longer starting. I checked `phpinfo()` and found that the local value was correct (`../session`), but the master value was incorrect (`C:\xamp\temp`). I tried changing the php.ini file value from `session.save_path="C:\xamp\tmp"` to `session.save_path="../session"` to no avail.

Additionally, when I go into the "session" folder I created, there are multiple session files included. When I click on them, they are empty. However, when I click on the session files that were stored in the default file ("temp"), they are full of code. Could these files relate to the problem?

**Question**

How do I set `session.save_path` without messing up the sessions starting?

**Things I Have Tried**

I have already tried doing the same thing in `.htaccess` with the code

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 18000
php_value session.save_path ../session
```

which didn't work, either. Any ideas on how to fix this problem? Let me know if there is any confusion. Thanks.

Comment: Did you contact your provider support hotline and/or read their FAQ's? Depending on your providers server configuration, it's is possible that they do not allow overwriting of certain configuration!

Comment: And second, I would recommend using an absolute path for `session.save_path`.

Comment: @Martin I have not contacted them yet. However, this problem exists not only on Bluehost, but on my local server, so I believe it's a problem with my code. I will try the absolute path option and get back to you.